# OllyDbg: MessageBoxA causes access violation

Tags: assembly, code-injection, ollydbg

I am trying to inject code for the first time and basically everything works so far.. but the problem is, that after I run the program and it calls method MessageBoxA() an access violation occurs.

The problem is, that the ESI cpu register does not have a valid value.

MessageBoxA() invokes

```
 PUSH DWORD PTR DS:[ESI-5]
```

right after it is called. What do I have to store in ESI to not get this error? I have pushed the arguments for this method onto the stack so I just don't know what this instruction wants from me ..

If you need more information please let me know.

Thank you.

---

**EDIT**

The very first instruction of the program jumps to my code. After I call the MessageBoxA I jump back to the stanard program (which doesnt matter at the moment)

[image]

Here you see where the program goes after I called MessageBoxA. Already the third instruction causes the problem.

[image]

I hope this helps ^^

Comment: I think you're have corrupted the call address, Don't think that `MessageBoxA` would start with such an instruction. If anything, it should start with a two-byte `NOP`.

Comment: I dont know.. I just call the address I found inside the executable module user32.dll. Module name is 'mss32' and I jump to the address of '%&USER32.MessageBoxA'

Comment: Put up a shot of the call or something, need more information.

Comment: added two screenshots. (i just saw that it's hard to read. if you cope the picture URL and follow that link it should be fine)

Comment: I don't get how you can end up at **2113e177** by calling **206fda7a**. And what's there doesn't look like proper code.

Comment: I instruct CALL 2113E178 to jump to the MessageBoxA() method. I didn't touch anything but these few bytes in the first pic. Not sure what you mean by "not proper code". I just placed my code inside a code-cave.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29452/discussion-between-jens-bjornhager-and-stefan-falk)